# FileVersionInfo of output from MSBuild

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have written an automated build process, as a .NET 4 application in C#. I am calling MSBuild.exe using `System.Diagnostics.Process`. The project being built is written in Delphi XE5. I then read the version of the executable that was just built:

```
version = System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(fileName).FileVersion;
```

(I can't use the `Sytem.Reflection.Assembly` class because it's a Delphi app).

If I do this in a Console app, it works great. The version comes back as e.g. "1.2.3.4". But exactly the same code as a Windows service, I get a null string, as if the file had no version info. Same OS credentials in both cases.

Maybe the version info is being cached from when it was being built by MSBuild? But why the difference between console and service? Any ideas how to force reload of version info? I tried `FileInfo.Refresh` - no difference.

(I know I could use MSBuild programmatically, it just seemed easier to call the exe, without having to implement a logger.)

**Update:**
I changed it to call MSBuild programmatically, through class `Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager`, instead of MSBuild.exe. Made no difference.

Comment: Hmm, no, the FileVersionInfo class is quite simplistic and has no strong dependency on the runtime environment.  The more likely explanation is that the build didn't go well and the executable file just doesn't have a version resource.  Easy to check with Explorer.

Comment: No problem with the executable - it has the correct version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it's not related to MSBuild at all. I think it's a bug in the CLR method, in the way it handles relative paths.

Before the call to `GetVersionInfo`, the current directory is changed. The path to the file is relative. Looking at the decompiled code for `GetVersionInfo`, it first checks the file exists:

```
if (!File.Exists(fileName))
{
  new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, FileVersionInfo.GetFullPathWithAssert(fileName)).Demand();
  throw new FileNotFoundException(fileName);
}
```

No exception is thrown, so that bit is happy with the relative path.

But by the time `fileName` gets through to the API methods in `Microsoft.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods`, it's not recognised:

```
int fileVersionInfoSize = Microsoft.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetFileVersionInfoSize(fileName, out handle);
```

I converted `fileName` to a full path, before passing it into `GetVersionInfo`, and now it works.